# Ubuntu doesn’t shut off all the way

Tags: 20.04, shutdown

When I power off Ubuntu any type of way it just stays on this screen that says my computer logo and the Ubuntu logo at the bottom. I’m new to Linux and I suck, I just want to go to bed with my pc turning off all the way.

Comment: please add details of OS and hardware of your computer

Answer (score 0):

From the GUI:

- Select power symbol in upper right of Fossa Desktop screen
- Select "Power Off..."
- Select "Power Off"
  [image]
  [image]

From a command line (terminal) try:

`sudo shutdown -h now`

If neither of these power down your computer, it is most likely an issue with your Laptop/PC hardware configuration (sometimes referred to, quite inaccurately, as BIOS config).  Refer to your manufacturers documentation on how to enter and navigate the hardware setup; look for "power management" options.  Failing everything, most setup utilities have a "Revert to Factory Default" function - this is an option of last resort: it may solve your problem but it could just as easily leave your system unbootable!

**Addition:**
There are some Alienware systems that suffer from a kernel panic on shutdown due to an dw_i2c driver. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423797/how-do-i-disable-i2c-designware-support-when-its-not-built-as-a-module/446913#446913 for details.  For this situation,

- Add "initcall_blacklist=dw_i2c_init_driver" to the "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" in /etc/default/grub
- execute `sudo update-grub`
- Reboot: `sudo shutdown -r now`
- Shutdown: `sudo shutdown -h now`